# Advantages of projects issuing their own proprietary tokens

Tags: erc-20, cryptoeconomics, tokenomics

If you were to start a GameFi project, wouldn't you get more users using ETH than issuing your own tokens?
I myself would be interested in that if I could get ETH for completing the game.
Issuing your own tokens and increasing their value is a very difficult task - are the results worth the cost?

Answer (score 0):

> Issuing your own tokens and increasing their value is a very difficult task

From the founder point of view, the purpose of to issue an own token is to raise capital. It is not to increase the value of the token.

For the investors it is "it's not a fool who asks, but gives." If you invest in a token that does not accrue value, then it is a bad investment.